# How do I add a map to a map document field in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I add a `map` to a type `map` field in Firebase using flutter?
[image]

[image]

Here is the code in the image

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userNames').doc(docID).set(
              {
                'children': {
                  'childUserName': username.text,
                  'childPassword': password.text,
                  'childFirstName': firstName.text,
                  'childLastName': lastName.text,
                  'username': username.text,
                  'parentUID': currentUID,
                  'parentFirstName': parentFirstName,
                  'parentLastName': parentLastName,
                  'points': startingAmount.text,
                  'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                }
              },
              SetOptions(merge: true),
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a `Children` and `Child` data model, then write a toMap function using.

example:

```dart
class Children {
  final Child child;
  Children({
    required this.child,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'child': child.toMap(),
    };
  }
}


class Child {
  final String hello;
  Child({
    required this.hello,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'hello': hello,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo for the answer, but I do not understand how to use it. Can you edit the answer to include the fields I stated on the question's code snippet so I get an idea of how to use this?

Comment: map = Children(child : Child(hello: "World")).toMap();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userNames').doc(docID).set(
              map,
              SetOptions(merge: true),
            )